# Replace part of the string with n size with string of m size

Tags: c++, strings, pointers

I wanted to understand memory and pointers better before I endeavour into file path manipulations for larger project. This is simple *replace part of the string* test function that I need to rewrite into struct to call upon. I used scopes to test for memory leaking and changes, I work on Windows 7, CygWin and notepad++.

I am using `std::size_t` as an size representation due to:

> **A type whose size cannot be represented by std::size_t is ill-formed** mentioned by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) with *"std::size_t is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting"*.

I decided to go for the c-style null terminated character array since arguments passed through `main(int argc, char **argv)` are null terminated characters and system calls accept those best. It seemed beneficial to code parts that i need myself instead of relying on another library, and it is tiresome to keep track what is converted with `c_str()` and what isn't.

As mentioned above, this function is part of project that manipulates, changes and makes full or relative paths to the files. The character array helps me use `stat` that comes with CygWin to be able to automatically test if path is not accessible, directory or file. I could use `std::string` but that is an extra header and i plan serious expansions of file paths to include some custom behaviour - which isn't tied to this function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

size_t get_str_size(const char* temp){
            size_t s=0;
            while( temp[s] != '\0' )s++;
            return s;
        }

int main(int argc, char **argv){ 

    const char * temp = "sublime/subliminal/sfit.exe"; // example string
    std::cout << &temp << "\t" << temp << std::endl; // prints out address and value
    { // wild scope to help me navigate and debug
        const char* shitcake = "sfitcake"; // string to be put in place of sfit
        size_t ldelim = 0;  // / last delimiter 
        size_t edelim = 0;  // . end delimiter
        size_t original_size = get_str_size(temp);

        // finding the necessary indexes of charachters  
        for( int i =0 ; i <= original_size; i++ ){
                if( temp[i]=='/' ){ldelim=i;}
                if( temp[i]=='.' ){edelim=i;}
            }

        // calculating size that influences the char array
        size_t old_size = edelim - ldelim -1;  // current char array size(-1 to remove last delimiter)
        size_t new_size = get_str_size(shitcake); // new char array size

        // char array duplication , since original string is const
        char* tempcopy = new char[original_size]; // holds the copy of the temp
        for( int i =0 ; i < original_size; i++ ){ tempcopy[i] = temp[i]; }

        // value to be constructed
        char *new_version = new char[ original_size + (new_size-old_size) ];

        // filling the part before replacement happen       
        for( int i =0 ; i <=ldelim; i++ )               { new_version[i] = tempcopy[i]; }
        // filling replaced char array
        for( int i =0 ; i <= new_size;i++ )             { new_version[i+1+ldelim] = shitcake[i]; }
        // the rest of original string
        for( int i =edelim ; i < original_size;i++ )    { new_version[i+old_size] = tempcopy[i];}

        //conversion back to const char* with expanded size and new value
        temp = (const char*)new_version;

        //deleting pointers
        delete tempcopy;
        delete new_version;
    }
    std::cout << &temp << "\t" << temp << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output i am getting is:

```
0xffffcbb8  sublime/subliminal/sfit.exe
0xffffcbb8  sublime/subliminal/sfitcake.exe
```

Which means it works, but i am afraid of pointer not changing memory address even though the size and value changed.

Main concerns and desires for code:

- Removing chance of *dangling pointer* and *memory issue*
- Fast and readable code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no definition in scope for `size_t`.  Since the description implies that you want `std::size_t`, you'll need

```
#include <cstddef>
using std::size_t
```

But I recommend just writing `std::size_t` in full where you use it - that's much clearer to readers.

---

> ```
> size_t get_str_size(const char* temp){
>             size_t s=0;
>             while( temp[s] != '\0' )s++;
>             return s;
>         }
> ```

You've just re-implemented `std::strlen()` for no good reason.

---

> ```
>     char* tempcopy = new char[original_size]; // holds the copy of the temp
>
>     char *new_version = new char[ original_size + (new_size-old_size) ];
>
>     delete tempcopy;
>     delete new_version;
> ```

Memory allocated with `new[]` must be released using `delete[]` (not `delete`).  Valgrind will catch this error for you.

---

We have a memory leak if the first allocation succeeds and the second fails, because there is no `delete[] tempcopy` if an `std::bad_alloc` is thrown.

---

We reference deleted memory here:

> ```
>     temp = (const char*)new_version;
>
>     delete new_version;
>
>     std::cout << &temp << "\t" << temp << std::endl;
> ```

That's Undefined Behaviour (and also caught by Valgrind - I really recommend you run your code under Memcheck, or any similar tool of your choice).

---

> ```
> int main(int argc, char **argv){
> ```

Since we never use the arguments, there's no need to give them names; moreover, there's a signature of `main()` we can use with no arguments:

```
int main()
```

---

> ```
>      for( int i =0 ; i <= original_size; i++ ){
> ```

Avoid comparing signed values (such as `i`) against unsigned ones (such as `original_size`).  We probably want the range of `i` to match, too, so just use the same type for both.

---

The code isn't very robust against a range of inputs.  In particular, if `edelim` is less than `ldelim`, we'll get (unsigned) integer overflow when we compute `old_size`, giving incorrect results.

---

Overall, the code looks very much like C code - and poor C code at that (e.g. copying 1 char at a time, rather than with `memcpy()`).  A C++ implementation (using `std::string`) is much shorter and more natural.

Comment: Your platform happens to define `size_t` in the global namespace as well as in `std`.  This is allowed, but not required; while it works for you, you can't portably depend on that extra definition.

Comment: Toby, thank you for response. *For all that look upon this comment section, I wrote an follow up question about `size_t` and Toby answered. I thought comment was unclear and I deleted it without noticing that Toby answered.*

Comment: So i would need to include standard c definitions everytime i use `size_t` to maximise portability ?

Comment: There are six different headers that declare `std::size_t` - consult your usual reference if you've forgotten which they are.  (I generally use CPP Reference, which is also available [as a web site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).)

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this C++, but your code does not at all look like C++.  It looks like C with `malloc` replaced by `new` and `printf` replaced by `std::cout`.  You can use C++ standard library facilities to simplify your code.  In this case, you can simplify your code with `std::string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

std::string replace(std::string_view string, std::string_view pattern, std::string_view replace)
{
    std::string result;

    while (true) {
        auto index = string.find(pattern);
        result.append(string, 0, index);
        if (index == string.npos)
            break;
        string.remove_prefix(index + pattern.size());
        result += replace;
    }
    return result;
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BvpRgVW7IWfi8Pmi))